# Does saying a being’s name allow them to spy on you?

Tags: percy-jackson, rick-riordan

In the *Percy Jackson* universe, it has been stated that names have power, and even saying Kronos’s name makes the room colder.

But does saying a being’s name draw its attention, and let them spy on you?

Comment: [I Know Your True Name](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IKnowYourTrueName)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there was a case for that in the books at least once, but don't have sources on me now.

Comment: Is there anyway I can improve my answer?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the whole "Names Have Power" thing was dropped pretty early on in the series. In *The Lightning Thief*, it's implied that saying the true name of a powerful being at least alerts them that you're talking about them. Because of this, the Furies, the Minotaur, etc. are referred to by titles/nicknames rather than their real names. However, later on in the series, monsters, titans, gods and other beings are referred to by direct name with absolutely nothing negative happening and no mention of a risk.